# Firebase. Push notification перестают приходить

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-уведомления, google-services

Есть android app с:

```
gms:google-services:3.0.0 
firebase-messaging:17.3.0 
firebase-core:16.0.3
google-services:4.0.1
```

При начале тестирования
с сервера первые несколько пушей приходять нормально, но в процессе доставка либо замедляется либо отваливается полностью. Четко видна связь с запросом отправки пушей(если спамить).С сервера пуши к firebase отправляются вовремя.

Есть подозрение что по какойто причине пуш может быть доставлен до телефона но не доходит до FirebaseMessagingService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решением оказалось в отсутствии поля title в отделении notification у json

```
"message": {
    "data": {
        .......
    },
    "notification" : {
        "title" : " "    <- должна быть не пустая строка
    },
    "android": {
        .......         
    },
   .......
 }
```

если пуш не будет иметь тайтла то после нескольких отправок телефон начнет игнорировать такие пуши и не доставлять их до метода onMessageReceive в приложении.

Дополнение:

решение вверху не полное та как в таком подходе меняется тип пуша. Основная же проблема в том что push без "notification" блока не должен иметь поле "collapse_key" (кроме того что оно не имеет смысла для пушей без "notification" блока он приводит к багу описаному в вопросе).